# How to Remove Minor Variations from a Column of Text

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

[I Would like to clean a data set similar to this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXTfc.jpg)

I have a large dataset with more than 5 columns with 10000 rows. Each column has textual information in it and I want to encode the values in each column and send them to a Multi Class classifier.

There are small variations between field values that I want to get rid of.

For example: If I have "Hello all this is sunday" and "This is sunday" I want to encode both of them as "This is Sunday".

Is there any approach for doing this?

Comment: It is up to you how to encode field values, of course, but have a look at `dict` (for mapping many values into one value) and `set` (for collecting unique values)

Comment: Can you explain me the dictionary approach with an example.

Comment: Akhil, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: I took some reference strings and passed one by one to the complete column and replaced them with the reference if I found some portion of string to that reference. But this is manual. I want the algorithm should decide what should be the reference string and replace the other strings that matches with the reference.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find common substrings automatically, and map longer strings onto the common substrings? (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: Yes, Exactly that's what I want to do

Comment: Ok, so are the substrings whole words or sequences of words? Case- insensitive? Must be greater than 5 letters long? Without some kind of constraint the auto mapping could take a long time

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, what you're wanting to do is quite tricky, and will depend on the nature of your data. The following approach works with the data you've shared with us so far but the rules may need further tuning.

1. Assume all eligible phrases are strict sub-strings of the cell being matched, i.e. `cell.find(phrase)` would be a positive integer

> **Example:** `send`, `send to`, `send to india` are all
>   sub-phrases of `send to India carefully`. (But not `send to carefully`)

2. collect all possible sub-phrases from a column of text cells

> **Example:** `send`, `send to`, `send to india` are all
>   sub-phrases of `send to India carefully` (but not the only ones)

3. derive a score for each unique sub-phrase based on a set of rules

> **Example:** you might add one point to a sub-phrase's score for each
>   time it occurs in a cell. If sub-phrase `send to india` occurs in 30 cells,
>   it has a score of `30` according to this rule.
>
> More than one rule can contribute to a sub-phrase's score.

4. the highest scoring sub-phrase that is found in a given cell will represent that cell in the final mapping.

> **Example:** both sub-phrases `send to india` and 
>   `send to india carefully` are found in a 
>   cell containing the text `send to India carefully`.
>   But if sub-phrase `send to india` has a score of `40` and 
>   sub-phrase `send to india carefully` has a score of `18`,
>   then the cell `send to India carefully` will be mapped to
>   `send to india`, the sub-phrase with the higher score.

In practice a combination of 'additive' rules and 'scaling' rules seems to work best. (Additive rules add or subtract `n` to a phrase score; scaling rules multiply or divide a phrase's overall score.)

```py
from collections import Counter


def compile_subphrases(text, minwords=1, include_self=True):
    """
    derive possible sub-phrases from a given text

    >>> list(compile_subphrases("send to india safely"))
    ['send', 'to', 'india', 'safely', 'send to', 'to india', \
'india safely', 'send to india', 'to india safely', \
'send to india safely']
    """
    words = text.split()
    text_length = len(words)
    max_phrase_length = text_length if include_self else text_length - 1
    for phrase_length in range(minwords, max_phrase_length + 1):
        n_length_phrases = (' '.join(words[r:r + phrase_length])
                            for r in range(text_length - phrase_length + 1))
        yield from n_length_phrases


def subphrase_rule_matches(text):
    global scores
    for phrase in compile_subphrases(text):
        # score for being somewhere in this piece of text
        if phrase in text:
            yield phrase, 1.0
        # score more for starting a cell and being a larger proportion of a phrase
        words = phrase.split()
        for pos, word in enumerate(words):
            if phrase.startswith(word):
                yield phrase, (len(words) / len(text) * (len(words) - pos))
                # phrase length 4, text 5 (high score) 4/5 * (4 - 0)
                break


def apply_scaling_rules():
    negative_endwords = [
        # articles
        'the', 'a', 'an',
        # adverbs
        'carefully', 'safely',
        # conjunctions
        'and', 'but', 'because',
        # prepositions
        'from', 'to'
    ]
    for phrase in scores:
        # prefer longer phrases
        words = phrase.split()
        scores[phrase] = scores[phrase] * len(words) * 2
        # reduce sub-phrase score if it ends in certain words
        if words[-1] in negative_endwords:
            scores[phrase] = scores[phrase] / 3


def calculate_phrase_scores():
    for cell in column:
        for phrase, points in subphrase_rule_matches(cell.lower()):
            scores[phrase] += points
    apply_scaling_rules()


def list_top_n_phrases(n=10):
    phrase_scores = [(phrase, score) for phrase, score in scores.most_common()]
    print(f'Top {n} sub-phrases...')
    print()
    headings = f'{"Sub-phrase":33s}Score'
    print(headings)
    print('-' * len(headings))
    for phrase, score in phrase_scores[:n]:
        print(f'{phrase:33s}{score:.1f}')


def generate_mappings():
    mapping = {}
    for cell in column:
        phrases = compile_subphrases(cell.lower())
        phrase_scores = {phrase: scores[phrase] for phrase in phrases}
        highest_scorer = Counter(phrase_scores).most_common(n=1)[0]
        top_phrase, _ = highest_scorer
        mapping[cell] = top_phrase
    return mapping


def list_mappings(mapping):
    print()
    print('Mapping cell texts to common sub-phrases...')
    print()
    headings = f'{"Cell text":35s}Mapped to Sub-phrase'
    print(headings)
    print('-' * len(headings))
    for cell, phrase in mapping.items():
        print(f'{cell:35s}{phrase}')


column = [
    'This is an apple from Asia',
    'This is an apple',
    'Send to the market',
    'Send to the market carefully',
    'send to India',
    'send to India safely',
    'Packed to send to India safely',
    'send to India on Blue Dart',
    'If safe send to India',
]

scores = Counter()
calculate_phrase_scores()
list_top_n_phrases()
mappings = generate_mappings()
list_mappings(mappings)
```

The results show that the current rules work for the cases you've mentioned
 in the question and comments:

```
>>> python automap.py
Top 10 sub-phrases...

Sub-phrase                       Score
--------------------------------------
send to india                    43.3
this is an apple                 28.9
this is an apple from asia       28.6
send to india on blue dart       28.6
send to the market               27.7
to india                         23.9
if safe send to india            21.9
is an apple from asia            19.6
send to india on blue            19.6
to india on blue dart            19.6

Mapping cell texts to common sub-phrases...

Cell text                          Mapped to Sub-phrase
-------------------------------------------------------
This is an apple from Asia         this is an apple
This is an apple                   this is an apple
Send to the market                 send to the market
Send to the market carefully       send to the market
send to India                      send to india
send to India safely               send to india
Packed to send to India safely     send to india
send to India on Blue Dart         send to india
If safe send to India              send to india
```

The trick is to write sub-phrase scoring rules that select appropriate, relevant sub-phrases. The above rules work for the small number of examples you gave us in the question and comments on other answers.

Comment: That's a great explanation. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks Akhil. If it feels right, please mark this as the preferred answer so others can find it

Comment: @Akhil I think the answer deserves a "preferred answer" :) Please consider helping others to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If your only requirement is that one is a substring of the other you can do something like this:

```py
a = 'Hello all this is sunday'
b = 'This is sunday'


def replace_str(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    longest, shortest = (a, b) if len(a) > len(b) else (b, a)
    return shortest if shortest.lower() in longest.lower() else None


print(replace_str(a, b))

>>> 'This is sunday'
```

Comment: This helps if we have only 2 types of strings. But in my dataset one column have 1000 different strings with a possibility of replacing a set of 5 to 10 strings with the shortest one among them.

Comment: And what's the problem? Group similar strings and replace them with the code above. @AkhilKumarPenugonda

Comment: send to India, 
send to India safely, 
Packed to send to India safely,  
send to India on Blue Dart, 
If safe send to India............ All these should be replaced as Send to India. And there are many of this type in a single column. So the algo we write should dynamically take some reference and match with longer strings and replace them.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the likely strings you can use this code for example:

```
a="This is sunday"
b="Hello all this is sunday"
if a.lower() in b:
    b=a
    print(b)
```

Comment: That's the problem here we don't know the likely strings. The algorithm should fetch some most commonly seen sub string and replace all the larger strings with that particular sub string in that with the substring.